# Requirements for MATLAB Editor Run button? Script runs from Command Window but not from the Editor

Tags: matlab, function, editor

The script is saved, in the correct directory, with no syntax problems (I made a very very simple script that just does a test print).

No issues when running from the Command Window, but pressing the green Run button in the Editor (or pressing F5) does absolutely nothing.

I compared the Run Configuration to other scripts that work, and see no differences.

Are there any requirements I'm not aware of for having a script be runnable with F5? Is it running and just not reporting to the Command Window?

MATLAB R2012a

```
disp('test');

for i=1:10
    disp(i);
end
```

Running from the Command Window, it prints and the filename shows up in Command History. Nothing happens when I click the Run button. I also made a version with a simple function and that doesn't work either. Run settings were left as default which works for other scripts/functions.

**ETA:** The problem is now resolved, without any action on my part. Came in to work this morning and the Run button just magically works again. Didn't change any settings at all or do anything differently.

Even though this is solved now, I'd still love to hear any ideas on why this was happening. Is this a known bug in the Matlab Editor?

Comment: FYI I've looked through the documentation for the Editor, and I couldn't find anything on using the Run button specifically. it just says it's an alternative to running from the Command Window. From what I can tell, if there are no problems compiling then it should be the same between the Command Window and the Run button.

Comment: Does your script actually display anything  or create any variables so that you know it's run? Try putting a `disp('here')` statement somewhere in it. I guarantee that it's being run.

Comment: As I said, it does a test print. The first line is disp('test'); to see that it's working. When I run it from the Command Window, it prints. When I use the Run button, it doesn't.

Comment: can you share a [mcve]

Comment: If it's a _very simple script_, I suggest you post it here, it might help people understand what is going wrong with it. Do not post it in comment though, edit your original post to include the script. Also please indicate your Matlab version.

Comment: Please, share the code so we can try to reproduce it. This *may* be a bug, and if tht is the case you'd need to contact MATHWORKS, but first make sure we can reproduce it. Also share your MATLAB version

Comment: I added example code, the version, and more info.

Comment: <<Run settings were left as default which works for other scripts/functions. >>, so you mean you can run other scripts using the "Run" button, but not this demo script?

Comment: Yes. Using the Run button, I can run other scripts that have been previously written, but not this test script or any other new script.

Comment: What is the name of your script?

Comment: See ETA in my post -- came in to work this morning and it works now, without my changing anything. Is this a known Editor bug?